# WPF: Multiple screens

Tags: c#, wpf, screensaver

I'm writing a screensaver in WPF.  I have the screensaver working, however, it only displays on my main monitor.  Is there a way to "black out" or draw graphics to additional monitors when the user has multiple displays?  I've done some searching around, but haven't found anything relevant.

**UPDATE**

From ananthonline's answer below, I was able to accomplish the "black out" effect on non-primary displays using the following window:

```
<Window x:Class="ScreenSaver.BlackOut"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Cursor="None" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="Black">
</Window>
```

and initializing one for each screen in `App.xaml.cs` using the following process:

```
foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    if (s != Screen.PrimaryScreen)
    {
        BlackOut blackOut = new BlackOut();
        blackOut.Top = s.WorkingArea.Top;
        blackOut.Left = s.WorkingArea.Left;
        blackOut.Width = s.WorkingArea.Width;
        blackOut.Height = s.WorkingArea.Height;
        blackOut.Show();
    }
}
```

Note an import to `System.Windows.Forms` is required to access the `Screen` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the System.Drawing.Screen.* classes to set up multiple windows on each screen. Mind that you don't set each window to be maximized, but a properly sized, border less window.

Also - you might want to remember that the total bounds of the multi monitor setup may not always be a rectangle (if you plan to "union" all the bounds to create a window spanning all monitors).